# how that the complex matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial, similar-matrices

**Show that the complex matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar.**

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $,   $B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
\end{bmatrix} $

My attempt:

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p_A(x)=x^4-1$ and so, $p_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)$ then of minimal polynomial is $m_A(x)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)$ what means $A$ is diagonalizable and $B$ is the matrix diagonal that we obtain by diagonalization, then $A$ is similar to $B$. Is this correct?

Comment: Your argument convinced me! I would just add a sentence on why $B$ is the diagonal matrix similar to $A$: because the space dimension is equal to $4$ and the minimal polynomial of $A$ has $4$ different roots that are the elements of the diagonal of $B$.